# Query the number of times a student has participated in each subject's exams

Tags: sql

There are three tables in my PieCloudDB Database: Student table, Subject table, and Exam table. I want to know the number of times each student has participated in exams for each subject (if they haven't participated, output 0).

I tried this query, but it doesn't output students with an exam count of 0.

```
SELECT student_id, subject_name, COUNT(*) AS test_count
FROM Examinations
GROUP BY student_id, subject_name
ORDER BY student_id, subject_name;
```

example data：

| student_id | student_name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Alice |
| 2 | Bob |
| 6 | Joe |
| 13 | John |

| subject_name |
| --- |
| Math |
| Physics |
| Philosophy |

| student_id | subject_name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Math |
| 1 | Physics |
| 1 | Philosophy |
| 2 | Philosophy |
| 1 | Physics |
| 1 | Math |
| 13 | Math |
| 13 | Philosophy |
| 13 | Physics |
| 2 | Math |
| 1 | Math |

outcome：

| student_id | student_name | subject_name | test_count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Alice | Math | 3 |
| 1 | Alice | Physics | 2 |
| 1 | Alice | Philosophy | 1 |
| 2 | Bob | Math | 1 |
| 2 | Bob | Physics | 0 |
| 2 | Bob | Philosophy | 1 |
| 6 | Joe | Math | 0 |
| 6 | Joe | Physics | 0 |
| 6 | Joe | Philosophy | 0 |
| 13 | John | Math | 1 |
| 13 | John | Physics | 1 |
| 13 | John | Philosophy | 1 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using a `CROSS JOIN` between the `Student` and `Subject` tables to generate all possible combinations. Then, `LEFT JOIN`ing with the `Exam` table to get the counts.

```
SELECT 
  s.student_id, 
  s.student_name, 
  sub.subject_name, 
  COUNT(e.student_id) AS test_count 
FROM 
  Student s CROSS 
  JOIN Subject sub 
  LEFT JOIN Exam e ON s.student_id = e.student_id 
  AND sub.subject_name = e.subject_name 
GROUP BY 
  s.student_id, 
  sub.subject_name 
ORDER BY 
  s.student_id, 
  sub.subject_name;
```

**Output:**

| student_id | student_name | subject_name | test_count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Alice | Math | 3 |
| 1 | Alice | Philosophy | 1 |
| 1 | Alice | Physics | 2 |
| 2 | Bob | Math | 1 |
| 2 | Bob | Philosophy | 1 |
| 2 | Bob | Physics | 0 |
| 6 | Joe | Math | 0 |
| 6 | Joe | Philosophy | 0 |
| 6 | Joe | Physics | 0 |
| 13 | John | Math | 1 |
| 13 | John | Philosophy | 1 |
| 13 | John | Physics | 1 |

Answer (score 1):

You can use CROSS JOIN to obtain the Cartesian product of the Student and the Subject, which will give you all possible student-subject combinations. Then, using a subquery to calculate the number of exams taken by each student in each subject within these combinations. Try this query in your PieCloudDB Database.

```
SELECT S.student_id, S.student_name, SUB.subject_name,
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Examinations E
   WHERE E.student_id = S.student_id AND E.subject_name = SUB.subject_name) AS test_count
FROM Students S
CROSS JOIN Subjects SUB
ORDER BY S.student_id, SUB.subject_name;
```

Comment: It would help if you could add a small description of what your query is doing that's making it work compared to what the OP was using.

Comment: Thank you for your advice, I'll improve my answer.@Parrotmaster